# React-native transform style preserve 3d

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, transform, preserve-3d

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-cube.php) 3D animation in react-native. Everything is fine, but the problem is that react-native doesn't have `transform-style: preserve-3d`. Is there any alternative/polyfill to this or how can I accomplish my goal without using this property?

Comment: Isn't the default behavior equivalent to preserve-3d? I've just tried it on iOS and if I have a child with a 3d transform inside a view with a 3d transform, both are shown with their 3d transform.

Comment: @JeanRegisser Can you please provide a really simple css snippet?

Comment: I think the problem is actually the missing perspective property.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mirceageorgescu/pen/roblc
@Deepsy

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube
@Deepsy

Comment: still, looking for solutions